# How do I select all table rows containing certain text in one of the tr nodes up until the next hr element using xpath?

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data using xpath on the following:

```
<table class="ClassGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3"><hr></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1"><div class="ClassGridBox1">Anaheim (OC)<br>1240 S. WALNUT ANAHEIM, CA 92802<br><br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#104">Directions</a></div></td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, July 14</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl3_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4233&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, July 31</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl4_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4306&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 4</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3"><div class="ClassGridBoxNone">Class Full</div></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, August 18</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl6_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4346&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Thursday, August 30</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl7_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4313&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, September 8</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl8_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4330&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, September 18</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl9_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4331&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3"><hr></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1"><div class="ClassGridBox1">Burbank (LA)<br>2100 Empire Ave. Burbank, CA 91504<br><a target="_blank" class="gridDirections" href="/Classes/Directions.aspx#190">Directions</a></div></td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Saturday, July 21</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl11_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4242&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, August 28</div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow3">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox3"><a id="_ctl0_phMainContent_dgrdClasses__ctl12_hplAddToCart" class="whitelight" href="/validate.aspx?ClassID1=4243&amp;ClassID2=0">Book Now</a></div>
                    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="ClassGridRow1">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox1"></div>
                    </td><td class="ClassGridRow2">
                        <div class="ClassGridBox2">Tuesday, September 25</div>
                    </td></tr>
```

This is from the page https://www.notaryclasses.com/Classes/ClassSchedule.aspx?ClassType=N and the table structure is not very consistent. It appears that the only way I can even get close to extracting the content between the locations, which are all the td's that are **ClassGridBox1** class elements. I am trying to separate the content based on each location. There have been similar questions asked here previously, but I couldn't get any of those to work. I am simply trying to select all table rows up until there is an **hr** tag. What I have so far is: **//td/node()[preceding::tr[contains(/.,"Anaheim")] and following::td[contains(.,"Burbank")]]** .

This works okay for the first location only. If I attempt the same and try to stop at the next horizontal line, I have no luck. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Can you explicitly specify *desired output*?

Comment: I need everything in html starting with <td> and ending with  <td class="ClassGridRow1" colspan="3"><hr>

Comment: @Notary Classes I believe `//tr[position() > 1][position() < 8]` would be the only way to select the rows you want to process.